# How to share material change in multiplayer using Photon?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit, multiplayer

I'm working on a simple AR multiplayer app using this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3a-aaSYR8s
[SourceCode](https://github.com/Placenote/PlacenoteSDK-Multiplayer)

One user places a simple 3D cube somewhere in the room, then he and other players who will join the game can change its material, by clicking on a button, which executes a simple code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeMaterial : MonoBehaviour {


    public Material material_1;
    public Material material_2;
    public GameObject MainObject;


    void Update(){
        MainObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    }



    public void assignMaterialOne(){
            MainObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = material_1;
        }

    public void assignMaterialTwo(){
        MainObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = material_2;
    }



}
```

It works for the one player who placed the cube, but when other players join the game, they see the cube with its default material. They can change its material, but it will be visible only on their device.

How can I synchronize and display the change of the material or of the animation of the cube for all the users? Since the tutorial uses Photon, is there a way to implement it using Photon?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you'll need to send data over the network, in your case a reference to your materials ( you can use material names, but ints or bytes with a simply lookup table would be more efficient to save bandwith)

so on the instance your player owns and control, you set this material reference when you change it, and all other slaved instances will check that change and adjust their own instances accordingly.

to achieve this, you can either send an RPC ( a message that is sent over the network) if the data is changing very rarely on is discrete, or serialize data if it does change constantly ( like player position and rotation).

so I think you will be able to get away with an RPC in your case:

https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent